# Chrome html div has different sizes on different machines

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I have been developing some bootstrap forms in chrome.  On one machine, the pixel width of the html tag is an integer, 1905 px.  However on another machine, a laptop, the pixel width is a strange decimal, 1668.35789.  Both machines are running ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and chrome 35(latest stable version for ubuntu).  Of course, this is messing with the widths of many of the other elements on the page.  What might be going on here?

Update:  It is not a bootstrap issue.  It has something to do with rails.  A blank rails application without any added css, with all gems except for the rails gem removed produces the problem.  Html outside of rails does not produce the problem.

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Did you put the initial width in yourself? Bootstrap likes to format to all devices if you tend to use their classes.

Comment: I put no styling whatsoever on the html tag.  The problem exists even if I open up a blank project with nothing except for bootstrap styling applied.

Comment: It could be the resolutions on the different monitors.

Comment: Right but what about the different resolutions would be affecting the bootstrap in such a way?  Bootstrap adds very little styling to the html tag itself, or the body for that matter.  Furthermore, I tested out another monitor on the laptop with higher resolution and the problem persisted.

Comment: In addition, if I open up a blank html page without bootstrap applied, the html tag has an integer width again.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a bit more info such as any styling you have on the div elements? But if you have used percentages to set the width of the divs then Chrome will get your CSS resolution and divide that by the percentage width you have assigned.

So if you have a full HD screen and set a div to 10% width it will set it to 10% of 1920px so the div would be 192px in width.

After I saw that you have bootstrap, if you are using the grid based system that is favoured by bootstrap it is possible that each cell of the grid is taking a percentage and then the button is filling the parent.

As suggested below you could try the line for the input you are trying to fix the width of

```
    min-width: 1905px !important;
```

You may have to use important because bootstrap may overwrite your new styles

Comment: Well the issue is starting from the html tag itself.  That tag doesn't have any styling outside of what bootstrap gives it by default.  I forgot to mention I was using bootstrap in initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you satisfied with the following line?

`min-width: 1905px;`